# libmono-winforms2.0-cil package on Mac? MonoFramework

Tags: macos, mono

I want to install and run my software Process Analysis Toolkit (PAT) on my MacPro.

I have already installed MonoFramework and tried to run a hello.cs file for example to verify the installing result. It turns out that the cs and exe files can be executed successfully. However, when I run it in the Terminal with command `mono PAT.exe`, the software opened in a second then the window closed immediately and I get this error outputted:

> System.ArgumentException: A null reference or invalid value was found
>   [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]   at
>   System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (Status status) <0x6fdd778 +
>   0x0016b> in :0    at
>   System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush..ctor (Rectangle rect,
>   Color color1, Color color2, LinearGradientMode linearGradientMode)
>   <0x88cd8f8 + 0x00077> in :0    at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush:.ctor
>   (System.Drawing.Rectangle,System.Drawing.Color,System.Drawing.Color,System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProfessionalRenderer.OnRenderToolStripPanelBackground
>   (System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripPanelRenderEventArgs e) <0xe441950 +
>   0x0024b> in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripRenderer.DrawToolStripPanelBackground
>   (System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripPanelRenderEventArgs e) <0xe441930 +
>   0x00017> in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripPanel.OnPaintBackground
>   (System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) <0xe4417f0 + 0x00077> in
>   :0    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint
>   (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x88c8660 + 0x00155> in :0    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc
>   (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x7626390 + 0x0019b> in :0    at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc
>   (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x8892720 + 0x00017> in :0    at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc
>   (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x88c6940 + 0x0005b> in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage
>   (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x7626370 + 0x0001d> in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc
>   (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x7626340 + 0x0002b> in :0    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr
>   hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) <0x7624d18 + 0x0036f> in
>   :0

I'm not sure whether to install libmono-winforms2.0-cil package on my mac or does this package suit for Unix not Mac. I'm also not sure if solving this problem is the key point to run PAT.

Newbie to MonoFramework and could someone please give me some advices?

Comment: Are there any updates on this? I am struggling with the same error